# what if we retain or autorelease pool? why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

Language : Objective C

Questions:

- why we should always use 'drain' over 'release' for an autorelease pool ?
- what will happen if [pool retain]; ? why ?
- what will happen if [pool autorelease]; ? why ?

Comment: it throws exception when we retain or autorelease autoreleasepool object. But i want to know reason behind that.

Comment: why we can't reain or auto-release autorelease pool object ??

Comment: is this for homework ? The way the question is phrased makes it sound like it is.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't give a direct answer to this. However, there is a very clear answer; because it doesn't make sense.

P.S: drain and release are the exact same thing on an autorelease pool.

Comment: ok, i got drain vs release, but not convince about don't make sense answer. can you explain why it doesn't make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

Under garbage collection, `release` acts as a no-op, whereas `drain` triggers garbage collection, and then `release` (which is unusual), so `drain` should be the preferred way of emptying a pool.  `retain` and `autorelease` are intentionally disabled, as per the documentation.

Comment: as per doc, retain and autorelease disabled, but want to know an exact reason behind that.

Comment: My opinion is that it is done to make a simple api more complex, without need.  It would be just as simple to make drain a part of release, for example.  But the stated reason is the shift to @autorelease blocks in ARC, which move autorelease pools from being normal objects into being constructs of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

WWDC 2011 Session 323, [Introducing Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#introducing-automatic-reference-counting), explains that autorelease pools are not real objects, so they cannot be retained. Retaining an autorelease pool will cause an exception. Watch the video at 24:27 or read slide 23 of the [Keynote](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2011/adc_on_itunes__wwdc11_sessions__pdf/323_intro_to_arc_304repeat.pdf). You must be a registered developer to access.

Under ARC, autorelease syntax is a scoped block of code preceded by `@autorelease`.  According to Apple, this syntax more accurately describes what autorelease does under the hood.